# Stopping Executor service when user presses Back or Home button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, executorservice

I am trying to ensure that the executor service stops when the Back button or Home button is pressed.

Currently I have this code in my `onCreate` function in the `main activity` class:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final Wifi wifiObject = new Wifi((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));


    Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // For each AP in the database, we will fill the AP's ArrayList with their corresponding RSS values
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : AccessPoints.entrySet()) {
                int APNoToBeSent = 0;

                try {
                    wifiObject.scanWifi(entry.getKey(), accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }

                ++APNoToBeSent;
            }

            System.out.println("Mean AP0 = " + accessPointMeanRSSArrayList.get(0));
            System.out.println("Frqcy AP0 = " + accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList.get(0));

        }

    };

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I've been doing some reading on this but am unsure whether this should be happening in `onStop()` or `onPause()` or something completely different?

Comment: Override `onBackPressed` and `OnOptionsItemSelected` in home button

and do `shutdown()` or `shutdownnow()` the executor

[further reading on executors here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Did you search on SO?. `your_task.cancel(true)` should cancel the task.